# create a dataframe with all the responses from the api requests within foreachPartition

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, foreach, databricks

I am trying to execute an api call to get an object(json) from amazon s3 and I am using foreachPartition to execute multiple calls in parallel

```
df.rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
  //Initialize list buffer
  var buffer_accounts1 = new ListBuffer[String]()
 
  //Initialize Connection to amazon s3
  val s3 = s3clientConnection()
 
  partition.foreach(fun=>{
   //api to get object from s3 bucket
   //the first column of each row contains s3 object name
    val obj = getS3Object(s3, "my_bucket", fun.getString(0)).getContent
    val objString = IOUtils.toString(obj, "UTF-8")
    buffer_accounts1 += objString 
  })
  buffer_accounts1.toList.toDF("Object").write.parquet("dbfs:/mnt/test")
 })
```

From the foreachPartition I would like to store the string responses from all of the api calls made into a single dataframe. So if within the forEachPartition if I make a total of 100 api calls I would like to create a single dataframe that has all the 100 responses.

To do this I am creating a mutable list and want to convert it to a dataframe within foreachPartition  but we cannot create a dataframe outside of the driver.

I am trying to create a dataframe with all the responses from the total api calls within the foreachPartition so that I can apply further transformations. How can this be achieved?

Note:- I could write every response to disk as json and read them back in but that results in performance degradation because of a lot of disk I/O operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using mapPartitions

```
val df_response = df.mapPartitions(iterator => {
  val api_connect  = new s3clientBuild()
  val s3client = api_connect.s3connection(AccessKey, SecretKey)
  val resp = iterator.map(row =>{
    val name = getS3(row.getString(0), s3client)
    (name)
  })
   resp
  }).toDF("value")
```